# To find ONE function which has ONE of TWO possible shapes

Tags: calculus, derivatives, curves, regression, nonlinear-analysis

I looking for a function $y=f(x)$ (with minimum number of parameters $c_1,c_2,c_3,...$) satisfying all of the following properties:

- $f'(x)>0 \text{ } \forall \text{ } x \ge 0$,
- $\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ exists,
- Depending upon the values of the parameters, the number of inflection points of $f$ can be either $0$ or $1$ (as we require). So for example,
  $$y=c_1+c_2e^{{c_3}x}$$
  is not a valid form, because whatever values of the parameters $c_1,c_2,c_3$, we can not have $1$ inflection point if we require that.

---

The only form I get (by trying) is:

$$y=c_1+c_2e^{c_3(x^{c_4}+c_5)^{c_6}}$$

For example,

[image]

both blue curve and red curve have the same form, but we can fix the number of inflection points to be $0$ or $1$ is we wish by changing the parameters.

---

I found this:
$$y=c_1+c_2e^{c_3(x^{c_4}+c_5)^{c_6}}$$
can you suggest me other?

---

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What about $y=-e^{c_1x^{c_2}}$?  With $c_1=-1$ and $c_2=2$ there is 1 inflection point. With $c_1=1$ and $c_2=-1/2$ there are none.

Comment: @halrankard that is same as my function where you replaced $c_1$ with $0$, $c_2$ with $-1$, $c_3$ with $c_1$, $c_4$ with $c_2$, $c_5$ with $0$, and $c_6$ with $1$. That is what you did. I used $6$ parameters to do shifting when required.

Comment: Yes but I thought you were asking if you could do it with fewer parameters and still obtain the same properties, since the question says "with minimum number of parameters $c_1, c_2, c_3$". So I was just pointing out that two parameters are enough to get the behavior instead of six.

Comment: @halrankard Maybe I did not express my problem in a good way. Let me explain to you again in other way; I have many sets of data point (which are obtained experimentally). Some sets form no inflection point, and some form one inflection point. But surely the have the same equation form, but I do not know what is it.